# Python getimageinfo.py: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'w' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Facing an error in what seems to be a popular module/function ([getimageinfo.py](https://gist.github.com/bmamouri/55ac6bfa7ba5eee03da2eb9e4f7469d9)) in Python. Wanted to get image sizes without downloading them. However, running into following error:

```
>>> import getimageinfo
>>> import urllib2
>>> imgdata = urllib2.urlopen('https://cdn.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/python-modules.jpg')
>>> image_type,width,height = getimageinfo.getImageInfo(imgdata)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "getimageinfo.py", line 61, in getImageInfo
    width = int(w)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'w' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

The error seems to be coming from this section of the code:

```
# handle JPEGs
elif (size >= 2) and data.startswith('\377\330'):
    content_type = 'image/jpeg'
    jpeg = StringIO.StringIO(data)
    jpeg.read(2)
    b = jpeg.read(1)
    try:
        while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
            while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
            while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
            if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
                jpeg.read(3)
                h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", jpeg.read(4))
                break
            else:
                jpeg.read(int(struct.unpack(">H", jpeg.read(2))[0])-2)
            b = jpeg.read(1)
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)
    except struct.error:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

No one else seems to be facing this error for the module (at least no one has reported on Stackoverflow or other forums). How do I fix it? I wanted to get

```
                h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", jpeg.read(4))
```

line outside of the 'if' statement, but do not know how badly it will affect in cases where images have strange properties.
(New to coding)

Answer (score 0):

you have not declare default for `w` if the condition `(ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3)` is `False`, i add two comment lines when you can do it

```
    while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
        while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
        while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
        # HERE YOU NEED SET VALUE for w and h
        if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
            jpeg.read(3)
            h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", jpeg.read(4))
            break
        else:
            # Or HERE YOU NEED SET VALUE for w and h
            jpeg.read(int(struct.unpack(">H", jpeg.read(2))[0])-2)
        b = jpeg.read(1)
    width = int(w)
    height = int(h)
```

Comment: Ok. However, I guess, I will still need to figure out what it should be initialized with, since copying that 1 line as it is may give unintended results.  Looks like the Else clause is getting exercised a lot more than the author anticipated.